# Replace string with custom environment value

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, environment-variables, filebeat

I need to replace a specific string inside a file with the value of an environment variable, but I only get and empty value.

Here my code:

```yaml
- template:
    src: myfile.yml
    dest: /etc/myfile.yml
    mode: '0755'

- name: Update template env
  become: true
  shell: sed -i "s/HELK_ID/{{ lookup('env', 'HELK_ID') }}/" /etc/myfile.yml
```

Inside */etc/environment*:

```bash
HELK_ID=aaaa
```

How can I replace the string with the environment value?

Comment: [/etc/environment is used by PAM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables).

Answer (score 1):

> *I only get and empty value.*

Since [Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)

> *Like all [templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html#playbooks-templating) ... execute and are evaluated on the Ansible Control Machine ...*

the [`env` lookup – Read the value of environment variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/env_lookup.html)

> *Allows you to query the environment variables available on the Controller when you invoked Ansible.*

To gather the environment on the Remote Node it is recommended to [`gather_facts` about the `env`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692925/6771046). The answer under [Is it possible to gather only specific facts in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692925/6771046) show also how to debug.

After that tasks like

```yaml
- name: Update template env
  become: true
  shell: "sed -i 's/HELK_ID/{{ ansible_facts.env.HELK_ID }}/' /etc/myfile.yml"
```

are possible, whereby [the in the other answer here given example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76290954/6771046) for `replace`

```yaml
- replace:
   path: /tmp/myfile.yml
   regexp: 'HELK_ID'
   replace: "{{ ansible_facts.env.HELK_ID }}"
```

should be preferred since it is using the corresponding Ansible module.

---

Since you are using `template` to write out the file to the Remote Node, it might be possible to adjust your template file `myfile.yml.j2` with the environment varaible inside you'll end up with one single task.

**`myfile.yml.j2`**

```jinja2
HELK_ID = {{ ansible_facts.env.HELK_ID }}
```

**`playbook.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: filebeat_nodes
  become: false

  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "env"
    - "!all"
    - "!min"

  tasks:

  - template:
      src: myfile.yml.j2
      dest: /etc/myfile.yml
      mode: '0755'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect the module *shell* will provide you by default with the environment variables from */etc/environment*. The file [/etc/environment is used by PAM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables). If you need it, it's easier to read and parse the file on your own. For example, given the file

```ini
shell> cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
HELK_ID=aaaa
```

read the file

```yaml
    - command: cat /etc/environment
      register: env_out
```

and use the filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#converting-to-json)

```yaml
  env: "{{ env_out.stdout|community.general.jc('ini') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  env:
    HELK_ID: aaaa
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/myfile.yml 
var1: [foo, HELK_ID, bar]
```

Use the module [*replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#ansible-builtin-replace-module-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) to substitute the environment variable

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/myfile.yml
        regexp: 'HELK_ID'
        replace: "{{ env.HELK_ID }}"
```

gives, running with *'--check --diff'* options

```yaml
TASK [replace] *******************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/myfile.yml
+++ after: /tmp/myfile.yml
@@ -1 +1 @@
-var1: [foo, HELK_ID, bar]
+var1: [foo, aaaa, bar]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    env: "{{ env_out.stdout|community.general.jc('ini') }}"
    
  tasks:

    - command: cat /etc/environment
      register: env_out
      check_mode: false  # runs the command also with --check
    - debug:
        var: env
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/myfile.yml
        regexp: 'HELK_ID'
        replace: "{{ env.HELK_ID }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l localhost --check --diff

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  env:
    HELK_ID: aaaa
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

TASK [replace] *******************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/myfile.yml
+++ after: /tmp/myfile.yml
@@ -1 +1 @@
-var1: [foo, HELK_ID, bar]
+var1: [foo, aaaa, bar]

changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```